# After passing the session variable, explode and then the second array is not present

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I have passed a session array which has Name, Now the name could be only first name or both first and last name so if there is first name as well as last name i use explode and put first name in first name input and last name in last name input but if incase i dont have last name then 
explodes gives an error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\gym\bootstrap-3.3.5-dist\registration.php on line 17

```
<?php
session_start();

 $enqCustomer = $_SESSION['enqRegister'];

$enqCustomerid = $enqCustomer['id'];
$enqCustomerfullname = $enqCustomer['fname'];//For example name is Taha Dhailey
$enqArr = explode(" ",$enqCustomerfullname);
$enqCustomerfname = $enqArr[0];// Taha
$enqCustomerlname = $enqArr[1];// Dhailey

$enqCustomermobile = $enqCustomer['mobile'];
```

but if

```
 $enqCustomer = $_SESSION['enqRegister'];

$enqCustomerid = $enqCustomer['id'];
$enqCustomerfullname = $enqCustomer['fname'];//For example name is Taha
$enqArr = explode(" ",$enqCustomerfullname);
$enqCustomerfname = $enqArr[0];// is Taha
$enqCustomerlname = $enqArr[1];// is Null
```

while echoing `$enqCustomerlname` i get this error

> Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\gym\bootstrap-3.3.5-dist\registration.php on line 17"

Basically i want my server to tell that if second name is not there it should not take it.
Please help.

Comment: Please dont tell me to put error_reporting(0); if u have something else please help

Comment: Your code looks right but probably there is no space in the input. Therefore the `$enqArr[1]` does not contain anything and thus you get the `undefined offset` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$enqArr = explode(" ",$enqCustomerfullname);
$enqCustomerfname = $enqArr[0];
$enqCustomerlname = '';
if(isset($enqArr[1]))
   $enqCustomerlname = $enqArr[1];
```

Comment: thanks a lot that was a simple solutiuon just couldnt get it LOL